# Why is Armadillo so slow compared to a C-style array in a simple row-wise computationnal task

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, armadillo

I'm currently computing a small quantity for each value of a big matrix (millions of rows, number of columns < 1000) while considering each row independently.

More precisely, for each value *M*(*i*,*j*) in each row *i*, column *j* of this matrix, the quantity is simply [ *M*(*i*,*j*) - mean(*i*,*s*) ] / std(*i*,*s*) where *s* is the subset *s* in *M*(*i*,:) - *j*
in other words, *s* is the subset of all values of row *i* without value *j*.

I compared two implementations, one in C-style array and one in Armadillo, and Armadillo is roughly twice slower in termes of execution time. I would expect a similar or slighty slower execution time, but plain C arrays seem to dramatically improve the performance.

Is there any particular reason or somthing that I missed somewhere? Here is a example compiled with: `-O2 -lstdc++ -DARMA_DONT_USE_WRAPPER -lopenblas -llapack -lm`. Also tried to use `ARMA_NO_DEBUG` without success.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <armadillo>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std::chrono;

/***************************
 * main()
 ***************************/
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    unsigned nrows = 2000000; //number of rows
    unsigned ncols = 100; //number of cols

    const arma::mat huge_mat = arma::randn(nrows, ncols); //create huge matrix

    const arma::uvec vec = arma::linspace<arma::uvec>( 0, huge_mat.n_cols-1, huge_mat.n_cols); //create a vector of [0,...,n]
    arma::rowvec inds = arma::zeros<arma::rowvec>( huge_mat.n_cols-1 ); //-1 since we remove only one value at each step.
    arma::colvec simuT = arma::zeros<arma::colvec>( ncols ); //let's store the results in this simuT vector.

    high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();

    //compute some normalization over each value of line of this huge matrix:
    for(unsigned i=0; i < nrows; i++) {
        const arma::rowvec current_line = huge_mat.row(i); //extract current line

        //for each observation in current_line:
        for(unsigned j=0; j < ncols; j++) {

            //Take care of side effects first:
            if( j == 0 )
                inds = current_line(arma::span(1, ncols-1));
            else
                if( j == 1 ) {
                    inds(0) = current_line(0);
                    inds(arma::span(1, ncols-2)) = current_line( arma::span(2, ncols-1) );
                } else
                    inds(arma::span(0, j-1)) = current_line( arma::span(0, j-1) );

            //Let's do some computation: huge_mat(i,j) - mean[huge_mat(i,:)] / std([huge_mat(i,:)]) //can compute the mean and std first... for each line.
            simuT(j) = (current_line(j) - arma::mean(inds))  / ( std::sqrt( 1+1/((double) ncols-1) ) * arma::stddev(inds) );
        }
    }

    high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = duration_cast<seconds>( t2 - t1 ).count();
    std::cout << "ARMADILLO: " << duration << " secs\n";

    //------------------PLAIN C Array
    double *Mat_full;
    double *output;
    unsigned int i,j,k;
    double mean=0, stdd=0;
    double sq_diff_sum = 0, sum=0;
    double diff = 0;

    Mat_full = (double *) malloc(ncols * nrows * sizeof(double));
    output = (double *) malloc(nrows * ncols * sizeof(double));

    std::vector< std::vector<double> > V(huge_mat.n_rows);

    //Some UGLY copy from arma::mat to double* using a vector:
    for (size_t i = 0; i < huge_mat.n_rows; ++i)
        V[i] = arma::conv_to< std::vector<double> >::from(huge_mat.row(i));

    //then dump to Mat_full array:
    for (i=0; i < V.size(); i++)
        for (j=0; j < V[i].size(); j++)
            Mat_full[i + huge_mat.n_rows * j] = V[i][j];

    t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();

    for(i=0; i < nrows; i++)
        for(j=0; j < ncols; j++)
        {
            //compute mean of subset-------------------
            sum = 0;
            for(k = 0; k < ncols; k++)
                if(k!=j)
                {
                    sum = sum + Mat_full[i+k*nrows];
                }
            mean = sum / (ncols-1);

            //compute standard deviation of subset-----
            sq_diff_sum = 0;
            for(k = 0; k < ncols; k++)
                if(k!=j)
                {
                    diff = Mat_full[i+k*nrows] - mean;
                    sq_diff_sum += diff * diff;
                }
            stdd = sqrt(sq_diff_sum / (ncols-2));

            //export to plain C array:
            output[i*ncols+j] = (Mat_full[i+j*nrows] - mean) / (sqrt(1+1/(((double) ncols)-1))*stdd);
        }

    t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    duration = duration_cast<seconds>( t2 - t1 ).count();
    std::cout << "C ARRAY: " << duration << " secs\n";
}
```

In particular the calls to arma::mean and arma::stddev seem to perform poorly when comparing execution times. I did not perform any in-depth analyse of the size-effect over performance, but it seems that for small values of `nrows` the plain C tends to be (very much) faster. For a simple test using this 
setup i got:

```
ARMADILLO: 111 secs
C ARRAY: 79 secs
```

in execution time.

**EDIT**
Here is modification where we work column-wise instead of row-wise and treat each column independently, as suggested by @rubenvb and @mtall. The resulting execution time slightly is decreased (`ARMADILLO: 104 secs` now), thus showing some improvments over working row-wise:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <armadillo>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std::chrono;

/***************************
 * main()
 ***************************/
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    unsigned nrows = 100; //number of rows
    unsigned ncols = 2000000; //number of cols

    const arma::mat huge_mat = arma::randn(nrows, ncols); //create huge matrix

    const arma::uvec vec = arma::linspace<arma::uvec>( 0, huge_mat.n_rows-1, huge_mat.n_rows); //create a vector of [0,...,n]
    arma::colvec inds = arma::zeros<arma::colvec>( huge_mat.n_rows-1 ); //-1 since we remove only one value at each step.
    arma::rowvec simuT = arma::zeros<arma::rowvec>( nrows ); //let's store the results in this simuT vector.

    high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();

    //compute some normalization over each value of line of this huge matrix:
    for(unsigned i=0; i < ncols; i++) {
        const arma::colvec current_line = huge_mat.col(i); //extract current line

        //for each observation in current_line:
        for(unsigned j=0; j < nrows; j++) {

            //Take care of side effects first:
            if( j == 0 )
                inds = current_line(arma::span(1, nrows-1));
            else
                if( j == 1 ) {
                    inds(0) = current_line(0);
                    inds(arma::span(1, nrows-2)) = current_line( arma::span(2, nrows-1) );
                } else
                    inds(arma::span(0, j-1)) = current_line( arma::span(0, j-1) );

            //Let's do some computation: huge_mat(i,j) - mean[huge_mat(i,:)] / std([huge_mat(i,:)]) //can compute the mean and std first... for each line.
            simuT(j) = (current_line(j) - arma::mean(inds))  / ( std::sqrt( 1+1/((double) nrows-1) ) * arma::stddev(inds) );
        }
    }

    high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = duration_cast<seconds>( t2 - t1 ).count();
    std::cout << "ARMADILLO: " << duration << " secs\n";
}
```

Comment: First thing I would try is to reformulate your calculation into a matrix operation if possible. Second thing I would try is exchanging rows and columns which depending on the underlying data might leave you continuously cache missing here.

Comment: @rubenvb Considering each row indepdently is mandatory in my problem, I'm afraid it would be hard to reformulate it as a pure matrix operation as I would do in any matlab-like software. Cache missing is a brilliant suggestion will try that! Thank you.

Comment: Not related: A little optimisation for both codes. You can avoid the test `k != j`, then subtract the term corresponding to `j`.

Comment: Be careful, @Damien.  Computer arithmetic, especially floating-point arithmetic, is not algebraic.  Order of operations can matter, so the optimization you suggest may lead to a different result being computed.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I agree, the result may be different and certainly  will be. However, in this context, I guess the new value will be as reliable as the other. To be checked of course. My concern is the the compiler can be really disturbed by such an `if`inside a long summation, preventing him to perform some optimisation. Best solution will be to organised calculation such as a std::accumulate can be used

Comment: This appears to be a case of the so-called [abstraction penalty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-level_programming_language#Abstraction_penalty), where you "pay" for the nice syntax and easy to use features through somewhat reduced speed. In your code there is no need to shuffle data to `Mat_full` via the std::vector intermediary. You can directly access matrix data in Armadillo matrices via the [.memptr()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#memptr) member function. Example: `double* data = huge_mat.memptr()`. This means you can directly use C like access when needed.

Comment: Well, thank you for all these interesting (and informative) comments, I think i will need more in depth investigations to better assert what is going on i nthis example: Cache miss or Abstraction penalty or ... ?

Comment: @Grasshoper Also take into account that Armadillo stores data in [column major](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order#Column-major_order) format. Looks like your code accesses data rows by rows. This is not a good match.

Comment: @mtall this is reflecting rubenvb comment about cach miss. I should definitely try to transpose this matrix.

Comment: @Grasshoper Your code does a lot of unnecessary copying. Example: `const arma::colvec current_line = huge_mat.col(i)`. Avoid the copy by using `huge_mat.unsafe_col(i)` instead (see [associated documentation](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#submat)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that Armadillo uses [column-major ordering in mat](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Mat), while your C array uses row-major ordering. This is kind of a big deal because your processor can use [instruction vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) to process multiple elements at once, where this requires contiguous memory chunks.

To verify whether this is the cause, do the same calculation but for columns instead of rows, and check the difference.

Comment: Thank you, I already did the recommanded modification in the edit of the original post, and it improves efficientcy.